# https not being set for all urls

Tags: .htaccess, https

I need to set https on certain pages. To do this, in my .htaccess I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(login|message|enter|view|edit|submit)(.*)/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]
```

However this only works when the url is like **mysite.com/login** and not for **mysite.com/de/login**.
How can I get all these urls to be https regardless of what's infront of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*/|)(login|message|enter|view|edit|submit)(/.*|)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, seems to be working well! Would you mind explaing what the changes do exactly please?

Comment: I just changed the matching regex. Now it matches your URLs at the start (matching `^login`) or preceded by any text and a slash (`^something/login`). Additionally these URIs are followed by: end of text (`^login$`) or a slash and any arbitrary text (`^login/foo/bar$`).

Comment: Hi, also how can we include urls that in the form of: ?option=message&view=send&user=9 for example?

Comment: `?option=message&view=send&user=9` is basically a query string and in mod_rewrite you need to have a RewriteCond to match query strings like this: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=message&view=send&user=9$ [NC]`